# ¿Es posible envolver un ejecutable en un Frame de Java?

Tags: java, javafx

Tengo mi proyecto A en *JavaFX*, el cual quiere mandar a ejecutar un programa **.exe** externo. Esto lo hago bien, el problema es que según se me solicita, ese programa externo debe dar la sensación de pertenecer a mi proyecto. Por esto, me gustaría **envolver el programa *.exe* en un *Frame*** a fin de que este dé la sensación que estoy buscando. ¿Es esto posible?

Comment: Creo que no se puede.

Comment: Yo también creo eso, pero quiero re confirmar eso con otras opiniones. Gracias

Comment: solo para confirmar ese programa externo normalmente lo usas desde la consola o tiene interfaz gráfica propia?

Answer (score 0):

Si, podes usar  la clase Process para invocar el .exe dentro de un boton del JFrame

Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./miejecutable.exe");

Luego, incluis el archivo.exe dentro del .jar de tu proyecto para que quede como un recurso interno y listo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta Charlie, Pero esto haria solo que pueda ejecutar desde mi proyecto el .exe, mas no haria que pudiera colocarlo en un Jframe o algun componente similar a fin de colocarle un logo y titulo. o si?

Comment: Si el programa exe que deseas ejecutar es un programa que simplemente arroja texto en su salida podes leerla desde el metodo getInputStream() del process y mostrarlo como propio en tu clase visual. Ahora bien si el programa exe muestra una pantalla no se puede hacer nada.